# Understanding Norms on Vector Spaces

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a norm (not necessarily the standard norm) on $\mathbf R^2$ and $S$ be the set of all the vectors $v$ such that $\|v\|=1$.
For any point $p\in S$, let $\ell_p$ denote the line joining origin and $p$.
I think the following should hold:

> For any point $p\in S$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that no line parallel to $\ell_p$ intersects $U\cap S$ in more than one point.

This looks visually obvious, but I am facing difficulty proving this.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of how to approach this problem, but think that balls in any norm are convex sets. Also, since all norms are equivalent in $\Bbb R^2$, you can picture $U$ as a little disk.

Comment: You are right in saying that balls are convex because $\|tx+(1-t)y\|\leq t\|x\|+(1-t)\|y\|$.

Comment: I am interested in the solution. Can you explain it? and eventually draw the picture you need to explain it. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Ok. Let me wrtie it down.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Tell me if it checks out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma 1:** Let $A$ and $B$ be two points having norm $1$. Then theere is no point on the line segment joining $A$ and $B$ which has norm greater than $1$.

*Proof:* The norm is a convex function because $\|tx+(1-t)y\|\leq t\|x\|+(1-t)\|y\|$ for all points $x$ and $y$ and $t\in [0, 1]$.

**Lemma 2:** If there exist three points $A, B$ and $C$ having norm $1$, then all points inside the triangle $ABC$ have norm strictly less than $1$.

*Proof:* Suppose not. Then there is a point $D$ inside $ABC$ such that $D$ has norm $1$. Join $D$ with the origin and extend until we cut a side of $ABC$ at a point say $X$. Then $X$ has norm greater than $1$ but this is not possible by Lemma 1.

Now we come to the problem. Assume the contrary to the proposition and let $p$ be a point having norm $1$ such that every neighborhood of $p$ has two distinct points lying on a line parallel to $\ell_p$ such that both these points have norm $1$.

Consider this diagram:https://www.dropbox.com/s/om84ixeib7l943r/IMG_20150602_184748.jpg?dl=0

Let $m$ be a line parallel to $\ell_p$ having two points $q$ and $r$ such that norm of both $q$ and $r$ is $1$.

Note that by Lemma 2 we know that all points inside the triangle $pqr$ have norm strictly less than $1$.

Suppose we have a line $\ell$ (unmarked in the figure) between $\ell_p$ and $m$ and parallel to $\ell_p$ on which lie two points $s$ and $t$ both having norm $1$.

There are two possibilities.
In possibility 1 as shown in the figure, first note that we could choose $\ell$ such that $s$ and $t$ lie in a neighborhood of $p$ which is small enough such that the line joining the origin with $s$ has a point $s'$ which lies inside $pqr$. Now norm of $s'$ is greater than $1$, but this is not possible by Lemma 2.

In possibility 2, we have a triangle $ptr$ whose vertices all have norm $1$ inside of which lies a point $s$ which also has norm $1$. This again is not possible by Lemma 2.

Comment: Thank you :) I wasn't able to generalize this reasoning to $\mathbf R^3$. Tell me if you are interested in this.

Comment: Sorry, I delete by mistake my comment because I had to edit it to fix a typo. I said: Nice work! and a non important thing about Lemma 2.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. See my reply.

Comment: I think that for $\mathbb{R}^3$ you have to try to adapt your idea of getting a point of norm 1 inside a triangle whose vertices have norm 1. Namely,  take two parallel lines $m,n$ near $l_p$  assume that $m,n$ and $l_p$ are not complanar. Then you consider the prism whose base is a triangle in a perpendicular plane to $l_p$. Assume that on $m$ there are points $m_1,m_2$ of norm 1 and also on $n$ there are points of norm 1. Consider all possible triangles with vertices $m_1,m_2,n_1,n_2$ and $p$. It seems to me that one of the lines joining $0$ with one vertex intersects one interior, isn't it

Comment: I don't see how this helps. If you like, I can create a thread and you can post an answer? :)

Comment: You are right my comment does not help.  The problem is indeed interesting. I think you can ask this question. But I am not sure I am able to solve it.

Comment: I have posted a question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309420/understanding-norms-on-a-vector-space