# Understanding Norms On a Vector Space (Part II)

Tags: general-topology, geometry, normed-spaces

This question is motivated by a previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308427/understanding-norms-on-vector-spaces/1309260?noredirect=1#comment2659397_1309260) of mine.

Let $\|\cdot \|$ be any norm(not necessarily the standard norm) on $\mathbf R^3$ and $S$ be the set of all the points with norm $1$.
Let $p$ be point in $S$ and $\ell_p$ be the line joining the origin and $p$.

> Then there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $\mathbf R^3$ such that no line parallel to $\ell_p$ intersects $U\cap S$ in more than $1$ point.

The link given above discusses the same problem in $\mathbf R^2$, where I have provided an answer too. The reasoning given there does not extend to this case.

In fact, there is no reason to think that the proposition is false for any $n$.

My ultimate motive behind this is to show that $S$ is a topological manifold.

Comment: Rotation & implicit function theorem.

Comment: Norms a not necessarily smooth. So please elaborate.

Comment: Ahh, I missed the 'any' part.

Comment: Fixed that part :)

Comment: Cute problem. ${}{}$

Comment: How do you plan to use this result to show that $S$ is a manifold?

Comment: @Uzman Consider the $\mathbf R^3$ case. I will use the notation from the post. If the neighborhood $U$ as claimed in the proposition is found, then we have a neighborhood $U\cap S$ of $p$ in $S$. Now let $H$ be any plane passing through origin which does not contain $\ell_p$. Then we send a point $q\in U\cap S$ to a point on $H$ by moving it along the line parallel to $\ell_p$. This nothing but the composition $p_{H, \ell_p}\circ i:\ell_p\to H$, where $i:\ell_p\to \mathbf R^3$ is the inclusion map. Thus we get a bijective continuous map from $U\cap S$ into $H$. This is a local homeomorphsim

Comment: @Uzman (continued) becasue bijective continuous maps from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. (I forgot to mention that $p_{H, \ell_p}$ is the projection on $H$ with respect to $\ell_p$).

Comment: I see, nice idea!

Comment: That $S$ is a topological manifold can be proved by observing that $S$ is homeomorphic to the unit sphere of the euclidean norm. The map $v \to \frac{v}{\| v \|}$ is a homeomorphism since all norms of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalents. Then by using this homeomorphism you can put charts on $S$ by using charts on the standard unit sphere. But in any case your original question is interesting in itself.

Comment: I am having trouble about whether we know what "parallel" means for an arbitrary norm on the euclidean space.

Comment: @Uzman: I interpreted it as meaning that the line has the form $t \mapsto x+tp$ for some $x$. It is consistent with the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @Uzman copper.hat has made the right interpretation. I am using the usual geometry of $\mathbf R^3$. the topology under this geomtery is consistent with the particular norm chosen since all norms induce the same topology. So yes, parallel is how we usually define parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ denote the norm in question, since we are in finite dimensions, it is
equivalent to the usual Euclidean norm. (Presumably by parallel, you meant parallel in the Euclidean sense.)

Let $p \in S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, that is, $n(p)=1$.

Let $\pi$ be the orthogonal projection onto the subspace $\{x | \langle p, x \rangle = 0 \}$. Since $n \circ \pi$ is continuous, the
set $U = (n \circ \pi)^{-1}((-{1 \over 2} , {1 \over 2})) \cap \{x | \langle p, x \rangle > 0 \}$ is open and contains $p$.

If $L$ is a line parallel to $l_p$, then we can write $L$ as the
range of
$\lambda(t) = \delta + t p$, where $\delta \bot p$.

Suppose $t$ is such that $\lambda(t) \in U$, then
$n(\pi(\lambda(t))) = n(\delta) < {1 \over 2}$, and
$\langle p, \lambda(t) \rangle > 0$, hence $t >0$.

Now suppose $L$ intersects $S \cap U$ in two places, then there are
$0<t_1<t_2$ such that $n(\lambda(t_1)) = n(\lambda(t_2)) = 1$ and
$\lambda(t_k) \in U$.

The function $\phi(t)=n(\lambda(t))$ is convex, $\phi(t_1) = \phi(t_2) = 1$, hence we have $\phi(t) \ge 1$ for all $t \notin (t_1,t_2)$. In particular,
we have $\phi(0) = n(\lambda(0)) = n(\delta) \ge 1$, a contradiction. Hence
$L$ can intersect $U \cap S$ in at most one point.

Comment: What you wrote solves the OP question. Your key observation is the convexity of the norm when restricted to a line. Then outside of the segment whose endpoints are unit points the norm is $\geq 1$. If a sequence of such segments converges to the point $p$ then there is a sequence of vectors of norm $\geq 1$ converging to the origen. Contradiction.

Comment: There's brains beneath the hat. Masterful solution copper.hat!

Comment: Flattery will get you everywhere :-).